# Can I Connect Printer to Router via USB network adapter + USB B male to A Female "gender changer"?

Tags: wireless-networking, usb, printer

I am looking to buy a printer that has a USB type B connector only. I'd
like to connect it wirelessly to my router. The official way is to buy
a network printer adapter... expensive.

Do you think the following combo will work?

stick this into the printer:

http://tinyurl.com/8ut86lf

then stick this into the above:

http://tinyurl.com/98qelpe

Thanks!

Comment: Both links are now broken. :/

Answer (score 0):

No, simply because you would need the ability to install the drivers on the device (the printer).  The settings for connecting to a wireless device in this sort of setup would require the settings to be maintained on the Wireless USB adapter itself.  Unfortunately the person selling that device did not include the Minimum Recommended specifications portion which would include Operating System version(s).  I am currently unaware of a device that is able to maintain the settings in the adapter itself that isn't already considered a peripheral adapter, such as the network printer adapters.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why this won't work, but the most obvious is this -- you have no host. So neither device would ever try to talk to the other. The design of USB is asymmetric -- hosts always talk to devices. You have two devices, so nothing at all would happen. Each device would simply wait forever for a host to discover and configure it.